Regexp на извлечение подстроки


На входе дан массив с тремя элементами строками.

const res = ['<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2</SPAN>',
             '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">302</SPAN>',
             '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2 037</SPAN>'
            ]



На выходе нужно чтобы получилась строка: 'Итого заказов 2 на сумму 2339 Р


const result = `Итого заказов ${res[0].match(/(>|<)\s?\d+(\/\d+)?/g).map(s => s.replace(/[^\d/]|\/$/g, ''))
 на сумму ${Number(res[1].match(/(>|<)\s?\d+(\/\d+)?/g).map(s => s.replace(/[^\d/]|\/$/g, '')))
 + Number(res[2].match(/(>|<)\s?\d+(\/\d+)?/g).map(s => s.replace(/[^\d/]|\/$/g, '')))}`



Как написать корректное решение?

какая нафиг регулярка? во-первы тут можно спокойно подстрокой обойтись, во-вторых вообще обычный querySelector и операции с html использовать

а вообще, того, кто присылает данные в таком формате, надо жёстко ремнём пороть по заднице

Почему кстати итог тут 2 заказа на сумму 2339? какова логика?

@АлексейШиманский, подозреваю, что первая 2 - количество.

@АлексейШиманский При чем здесь дом, это не html страница. Я же написал что на входе приходит массив с тремя строками. Других вариантов нет. Изначально это отчет из 1С, который формируется и высылается в локальную папку в *.txt формате, что в нем внутри я указал выше. Node сервер берет этот файл и забирает нужные данные, мои регулярки работают, но в ситуации как в result[2] он не достает значение 2037, а только цифру 2.

Методы строк, например   *.replace(' ', '') не помогают, пробел все равно остается, что очень странно. Я так понимаю что это изначально был html документ, вышестоящий сервер из него каким то образом достает строки, кладет в массив и в файл .txt и высылает, а в dom изначально на месте этого пробела был  

@DmitryNefedov "Других вариантов нет" --- ну для суперджунов да - вариантов нет

@DmitryNefedov "отчет из 1С, который формируется и высылается в локальную папку " --- это вообще никого не интересует. Самая важная вещь тут то - что нужно работать с данными корректно. И в частности, данные надо отдавать как полагается, например сделав либо API, либо вспомогательный метод, который в файл будет записывать данные например в формате json, без html тегов....а не вот эту ерундистику



const res = ['<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2</SPAN>',
             '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">302</SPAN>',
             '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2 037</SPAN>'
            ];

let map = res.map(el => { 
    const parser = new DOMParser(); 
    const value = new DOMParser().parseFromString(el, 'text/html').querySelector('span').textContent;
    
    return Number(value.replaceAll(' ', '')); 
});

let sum = map.reduce((acc, el) => acc += el, 0);






const res = ['<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2</SPAN>',
             '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">302</SPAN>',
             '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2 037</SPAN>'
            ];

let map = res.map(el => { 
    let t1 = el.replace('</SPAN>', '');
    return Number(t1.substring(t1.lastIndexOf('>') + 1).replaceAll(' ', ''));    
});

let sum = map.reduce((acc, el) => acc += el, 0);




В общем, суть ясна. Допилить под себя не составляет труда (посчитать count и удалить одно значение из массива, если нужно)



var data = [
  '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2</SPAN>',
  '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">302</SPAN>',
  '<TD CLASS="R8C1"><SPAN STYLE="white-space:nowrap;max-width:0px;">2 037</SPAN>',
]

var [n, ...p] = data.map(x => +String(x.match(/[\s\d]+(?=<\/SPAN>)/)).replace(/\s/g, ''))
if (p.length !== n) throw new Error('Invalid count')

var sum = p.reduce((r, x) => r+x, 0)

console.log(`Итого заказов ${n} на сумму ${sum} Р`)



